# Preventing python3 script from terminating with ctrl c before operation is finished

Tags: python-3.x

I have an operation that writes to multiple files and due to the large amount of data, it requires a bit of time to write. How do I allow the user to terminate the program with Ctrl + C but allow the program to finish the operation before terminating. If one of the operation is initiated, the second operation needs to be completed too

```
while True:
    to_file = open("large_data.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")
    to_file.write(data)
    to_file.close()

    to_file = open("name.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")
    to_file.write(data)
    to_file.close()
```

Edit: I have tried try catching KeyboardInterrupt but whenever the ctrl + c occurs, it jumps out of the code and does into the except portion which is something i dont want to. For example if the Ctrl+C is triggered before the second portion of the code, the writing of data to name.txt is skipped.

Logic is that if i am writing to large_data.txt, it should also write to name.txt hence I want the codes to finish running even if KeyboardInterrupt is caught and terminates after the whole code is finished running.

Comment: KeyboardInterrupt jumps out of the code once the keyboardinterrupt is caught which will skip the second portion of the code but that is not what i want.

Comment: use `finally` which is always executed.